# Running Hadoop through cmd in Windows

Tags: hadoop

I am using Windows 8.1 and Hadoop 2.7.2 and when I try to run 
`hadoop namenode -format` it gives an error:

> IAVA_HOME is incorrectly set and update it at hadoop-env.cmd.

My JAVA_HOME path is : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65

and my Java_PATH:

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\include;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\lib;C:\Program Files\Java\jaf-1.1.1\activation.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\javamail-1.4.5\mail.jar;

and HADOOP_HOME : C:\cygwin64\home\sardwal\hadoop-2.7.2

and system variable Path:

> C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\include;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\lib;C:\adb;C:\cygwin64\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin;

So, can anyone tell me why it's giving the JAVA_HOME incorrectly_set error.
and, when I run Hadoop through cygwin, it's not executing 'jfs' command, giving error message:

> -bash, command not found.

So, how can I resolve both these situations?

Also, what are pros and cons of using cygwin or cmd to run Hadoop in Windows?

Comment: Hadoop on windows is never recommended. I would suggest you get a vm and setup hadoop on it for testing purpose. Can you echo JAVA_HOME and see if it is in environment or not.

Comment: It's giving me this path  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65

Comment: have you setup JAVA_HOME in your hadoop-env file, ?

Comment: yes, i have provided same path there too,

Answer (score 0):

Use Progra~1

i.e.

set JAVA_HOME=C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_65